Move assets from ledger
I have assets that were moved  to the stellar ledger when my coinbase wallet no longer supported xlm.  I need assistance to move my xlm from the stellar ledger to my coinbase exchange. Currently it does not give me the option to send it from the ledger.  Your help is greatly appreciated!
